# The data reader is incompatible?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am getting this error when I'm trying to getting data with the entity framework from the stored procedure.

**Note:** This stored procedure working fine when running it in the SQL server but throws an exception in the Entity framework.

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'BuyMediaModel.GetSpendBreakdownofBuyer_Result'. A member of the type, 'Impressions', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Here is my sp code.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[GetSpendBreakdownofBuyer]  

-- exec GetSpendBreakdownofBuyer '134', '2020'
@BuyerID varchar(100),
@Year varchar(20)
AS 
BEGIN 

SET FMTONLY OFF

SELECT 
   CASE WHEN 
        s.MediaType='Radio' 
            THEN 'Radio' 
            WHEN 
        s.MediaType='Newspaper' or s.MediaType='Magazine' 
            THEN 'Print'
            WHEN 
        s.MediaType='TV' 
            THEN 'TV' 
            WHEN 
        s.MediaType='Podcast' 
            THEN 'Podcast' 
            WHEN 
        s.MediaType='OOH' 
            THEN 'OOH' 
            WHEN 
        s.MediaType='Digital' 
            THEN 'Digital' 
         ELSE 'Other' 
        END AS 'MediaType',
        0 as Impressions,
    Convert(char(3), od.AdvertisingDate, 0) as 'Month',
    SUM(od.Price) as 'Budget_Spent'
INTO
    #TempBreakdown
FROM 
    tblOrder o 
JOIN 
    tblOrderDetail od 
ON
    o.Order_ID = od.Order_ID
JOIN 
    tblMediaSeller s 
ON  
    s.MediaSeller_ID =od.Seller_ID
WHERE 
    o.Buyer_ID in (select cast(item as int) from dbo.SplitString(@BuyerID) ) 
    AND  YEAR(od.AdvertisingDate)=@Year 
    AND od.Status in ('Ordered','Approved')
GROUP BY 
    Convert(char(3), od.AdvertisingDate, 0),
    s.MediaType
UNION
SELECT 
   'Other' as Mediatype,
   0 as Impressions,
   [Month],
   Sum(BudgetSpent) 
FROM 
   tblBudgetSpent
WHERE 
   Buyer_ID in (select cast(item as int) from dbo.SplitString(@BuyerID) )
   AND [Year]=@Year  
GROUP BY
    [Month]


SELECT 
   SUM(Budget_Spent) AS Total,
   --0 as Impressions,
   [month] 
INTO 
   #TempTotal 
FROM 
   #TempBreakdown 
GROUP BY 
   [month]

   
SELECT 
   b.MediaType,
   0 as Impressions,
   --CASE WHEN 
   --     t.Total <> 0 
         --    THEN((b.Budget_Spent/t.Total)*100) 
   --     ELSE
         --    0 END AS budget_spent,
   b.Budget_Spent,
   b.Month 
FROM 
    #TempBreakdown b 
JOIN 
    #TempTotal t 
ON 
    b.Month=t.Month
UNION
SELECT
    'Sales',  
    0 as Impressions, 
    Sales,
     [Month]
FROM
   tblSalesFigure
WHERE 
  BuyerID in (select cast(item as int) from dbo.SplitString(@BuyerID) )
   AND Year=@Year
   UNION
   SELECT
    'Impressions', 
    Impressions as Impressions,
    0 ,  
     [Month]
FROM
   tblMatrics
WHERE 
  Buyer_ID in (select cast(item as int) from dbo.SplitString(@BuyerID) )
   AND Year=@Year

END
```

Comment: Read the error again - it complains that the `Impressions` class doesn't have properties that match the result columns. We can't guess what those properties are.

Comment: First of all thanks for your comment @PanagiotisKanavos. Sir, I have written all code in question can you tell me what you want to know more to understand in details thanks.

Comment: There is mismatch in what you are returning from procedure and model, please try updating the entity once again with run custom tool.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is very product specific.)